How can I find samples of Radio occultation data in level 0?
I spent time finding samples in level 0 of Radio Occultation data. Exist several mission like COSMIC 1-2, SPIRE, GRACE, SAC-C, they recording data from level 1 and I need level 0 data to obtain samples of RF signal in intermediate frequency.

That was just a very short web search away:
https://www.cosmic.ucar.edu/what-we-do/cosmic-2/data
Contains literal terabytes of level 0 data, reader software and so on. The data format itself is described on here, and a more complete view of the L0-L1a and following levels chain can be found in

Zhang, B.; Ho, S.-p.; Cao, C.; Shao, X.; Dong, J.; Chen, Y. "Verification and Validation of the COSMIC-2 Excess Phase and Bending Angle Algorithms for Data Quality Assurance at STAR." Remote Sensing 2022, 14, 3288. doi 10.3390/rs14143288.  Available online.

